# Instantiate a class with a list

Tags: python, list, class, instantiation, attributeerror

I have a class called Player...

```py
class Player:
    def __init__(self,name,score=6):
        self.name=name
        self.score=score
        self.roll = 0
```

...And I have a class called Game

```py
class Game:
    def __init__(self,players):
        self.current_round = 1
        self.players=players
        self.winner_round= None
        self.player_names=[]
```

Currently I can instantiate the `Game` class with:

```py
    player_1=Player('Kid1')
    player_2=Player('Kid2')
    player_3=Player('Mom')
    player_4=Player('Dad')

    game = Game([player_1,player_2,player_3,player_4])
```

However, ideally I'd prefer to instantiate the `Game` class with something like:

```py
player_list=['Kid1','Kid2','Mom','Dad']
game = Game(player_list)
```

How might I achieve this?

**Solution:**

When creating / instantiating the `Game` class, via:

```py
game = Game(player_list)
```

I had not created any `Player` objects first. Since my `Game` class required players to exist, it was failing and giving the error of:

```sh
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'score'
```

This is because, according to `Game` there where no `Players`; hence there was no `score` for the `Game` class to use.

By instantiating `Game` via this command:

```py
game=Game([Player(name) for name in player_list])
```

I was now instantiating `Game` *and* creating the necessary `Player` objects at the same time.

There are many correct answers that demonstrate different ways to do this.

Comment: What _stops you_ from doing that right now?

Comment: Btw, note the possibility of `Game([Player(name) for name in player_list])`

Comment: The solution was ```game=Game([Player(s) for s in player_list])```, modified from your second comment. The ```Game``` class wasn't getting a properly initiated ```Player``` in my version [the error was ```AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'score'```].

Comment: There's no difference between choosing `name` and choosing `s` as your temporary identifier, unless there's something else using the name (which isn't evident in the given code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious solution (pointed out in the comments) is to create the list of `Player` objects in order to pass it to `Game`:

```
player_list = ['Kid1', 'Kid2', 'Mom', 'Dad']
game = Game([Player(s) for s in player_list])
```

Another option is to encapsulate this as a *class* method

```
class Game:
    def __init__(self, players):
        self.current_round = 1
        self.players = players
        self.winner_round = None

    @classmethod
    def from_names(cls, player_names):
        return cls([Player(s) for s in player_names])


player_list = ['Kid1', 'Kid2', 'Mom', 'Dad']
game = Game.from_names(player_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

To do it, you can instantiate the player in Game's constructor.

Something like :

```py
class Game:
    def __init__(self,players):
        self.current_round = 1
        self.players=[Player(name) for name in players]
        self.winner_round= None
        self.player_names=[]
```

Comment: Nice! Send the list of names and let the Game class create the Players!

Answer (score 0):

game = Game([Player ('jack')]) should work. Add more players to the list